# How to get current language code with Swift?

Tags: swift, nslocale

I want get the language code of the device (en, es...) in my app written with Swift. How can get this?

I'm trying this:

```
var preferredLanguages : NSLocale!
let pre = preferredLanguages.displayNameForKey(NSLocaleIdentifier, value: preferredLanguages)
```

But this returns nil.

Answer (score 247):

In Swift 3

```
let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode
```

Comment: should be :   Locale.current.identifier but  Locale.current.languageCode

for Chinese, it always return 'zh' , but it have to be distinguish zh-HK,  etc

Comment: @User9527 Because of you most likely didn't enable localization for that language in your project settings.

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Locale?'

Comment: As far as I notice, it will return actual language set in Settings -> General -> Language & Region -> iPhone Language ONLY IF localization for this language enabled in your project under Project -> Localizations. Otherwise it's development language.

Comment: How I make an executable binary that outputs this value, using only the commandline version of xcode?

Answer (score 141):

It's important to make the difference between the **App language** and the **device locale language** (The code below is in **Swift 3**)

Will return the **Device** language:

```
let locale = NSLocale.current.languageCode
```

Will return the **App** language:

```
let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between Device Language or App Language. Do you have any documentation about the difference?

Comment: @Jeremiah locale will contain the device language, for example your device language is configured to French. Pre will contain the user (Or App) preferred language, example: your App support only Chinese, so you can install a Chinese app on a French device. Hope I clarified this 4 u

Comment: When you say the device is configured to french what do you mean? It seems that if I change the language in settings to something other than english it is represented in preferredLanguages but not in languageCode. How is languageCode changed?

Comment: If you change the in settings to something other that English you will get its value in NSLocale.current.languageCode

Comment: Isn't it the other way around? 

When my app development language is EN and I run on a DE configured device, for which I have localized the app the result is:
`Locale.current.languageCode: de
    Locale.current.identifier: de_DE
    Locale.preferredLanguages[0]: de`

When my app development language is EN and I run on a FR configured device, for which I have *not* localized the app the result is:
    `Locale.current.languageCode: en
    Locale.current.identifier: en_FR
    Locale.preferredLanguages[0]: fr`

Comment: @ArjenHiemstra what I see here is that you're getting always the device language in preferredLanguages[0], probably you're not seeing your development language correctly! To force the App language you should do it via the Scheme, please check the url https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881

Comment: @ArjenHiemstra If you need more help we need to do it other way that here! Think of something.

Comment: I did set up schemes to test the above. 1 scheme witGerman/Germany and 1 scheme with French/France. The locale the app operates in is DE if I have a DE localization and EN (my development language) if I do not have the localization for the device. At least that is what I am seeing?

Comment: @ArjenHiemstra can you give me access to your code? A github link!

Comment: @raed Did you reproduce?

Comment: @ArjenHiemstra Sorry for being late, it's weird, but I m always getting DE for all parameters even if my device is EN or FR!

Comment: This is wrong for 1 more reason: iOS 13.1 introduces per-app language setting, and `Locale.preferredLanguages[0]` doesn't take that into account, whereas `Locale.current.languageCode` does.

Comment: I tried to find out how "iOS 13.1 per-app language setting" is done, and can't get it? My app supports 12 languages and is set by the device language settings. Looks like I should scan the list Locale.preferredLanguages from the top and see if I get any hit, if not English. But shall I declare the languages (capabilities) in the code of the app?

Comment: For me, inside the debugging console (lldb).
Both Locale.preferredLanguages[0] and NSLocale.current.languageCode
display the same answer "en", but my iPhone is not set to English.
Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: I think this is no longer working in new iOS versions! @Michel

Comment: This is the wrong way around... `Locale.current.languageCode` is the current app language

Comment: Locale.preferredLanguages.first is the language at the top of the Settings language selector. If that language is supported by iOS, it is the current device language. If not (if it came from the "Other Languages" list), the device language will be the first preferredLanguage which is supported. If your app is localized for it, it will also equal your app's current language, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 73):

**Swift 4 & 5:**

```
Locale.current.languageCode
```

Comment: Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'Locale?'

Comment: Try `Locale(identifier: Locale.current.identifier)`;

Comment: `Locale.autoupdatingCurrent.languageCode` is also available

Answer (score 60):

## TL;DR:

Use `Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]` to get the language your app's UI is currently displayed in. Don't use `Locale.current` because it describes the **region format** (time, currency, distance, etc) and has nothing to do with language.

## Detailed Answer:

The [definite answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/9246?answerId=26717022#26717022) about how to get the language(!) code for the language your app's UI is displayed in comes from Apple engineer Quinn "The Eskimo", and I quote/paraphrase for Swift:

> `Locale.current` returns the current locale, that is, the value set by **Settings > General > Language & Region > Region Formats**. It has nothing to do with the language that your app is running in. It's perfectly reasonable, and in fact quite common, for users in the field to have their locale and language set to 'conflicting' values. For example, a native English speaker living in France would have the language set to English but might choose to set the locale to French (so they get metric weights and measures, 24 time, and so on).

> The language that your app runs in is determined by the language setting, that is, **Settings > General > Language & Region > Preferred Language Order**.  When the system runs your app it takes this list of languages (the preferred list) and matches it against the list of languages that your app is localised into (the app list).  The first language in the preferred list that exists in the app list is the language chosen for the app.  This is what you'll find in the first entry of the main bundle's `preferredLocalizations` array.

## Language Name from Code

To get the human-readable name of a language from its code, you can use this:

```
let langCode = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations[0]
let usLocale = Locale(identifier: "en-US")
var langName = ""
if let languageName = usLocale.localizedString(forLanguageCode: langCode) {
    langName = languageName
}
```

This will give you the English name of the current UI language.

Comment: It could also be worthwhile considering using Locale.current instead of Locale(identifier: "en-US") so that the language name will be in the language itself. "Français" instead of "French" for instance

Comment: This should have way more upvotes. Although the question is about "device language", I think _this_ answer (i.e. UI language) is what people (including me) actually needed.

Comment: Quinn is worth his weight in gold!

Comment: @spartgw So true!

Comment: "Don't use Locale.current" should be in big red letters

Answer (score 48):

**Swift 3 & 4 & 4.2 & 5**

`Locale.current.languageCode` does not compile regularly. Because you did not implemented localization for your project.

You have two possible solutions

1) `String(Locale.preferredLanguages[0].prefix(2))` 
It returns phone lang properly.

If you want to get the type `en-En`, you can use `Locale.preferredLanguages[0]`

2)
Select `Project(MyApp)`->`Project (not Target)`-> press + button into `Localizations`, then add language which you want.

Comment: This is really interesting! Where did you read solution one? Cannot find this information in the apple documentation

Comment: This solution is right. I had tried much with other codes but it was due to 2) reason.

Answer (score 40):

In Swift 3:

```
NSLocale.current.languageCode
```

Answer (score 34):

To get current language used in your app (different than preferred languages)

```
NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleLanguageCode)!
```

Answer (score 22):

**swift 3**

```
let preferredLanguage = Locale.preferredLanguages[0] as String
print (preferredLanguage) //en-US

let arr = preferredLanguage.components(separatedBy: "-")
let deviceLanguage = arr.first
print (deviceLanguage) //en
```

Comment: Separate language code and country code by "-" is buggy. Your code will break on 
 some cases like 'zh-Hans-US'.

Comment: `let langStr = Locale.preferredLanguages.first!`this is what I have done reviewing this post. It's working, and I compare with my languages with `langStr.lowercased().contains("es")` for all spanish language variations for example.

Answer (score 14):

Swift 5.4:

```
let languagePrefix = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
print(languagePrefix)
```

Answer (score 13):

`Locale.current.languageCode` returns me wrong code, so I use these extensions:

```
extension Locale {
    static var preferredLanguageCode: String {
        guard let preferredLanguage = preferredLanguages.first,
              let code = Locale(identifier: preferredLanguage).languageCode else {
            return "en"
        }
        return code
    }
    
    static var preferredLanguageCodes: [String] {
        return Locale.preferredLanguages.compactMap({Locale(identifier: $0).languageCode})
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the correct solution!

Answer (score 10):

you may use the below code it works fine with swift 3

```
var preferredLanguage : String = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first!
```

Comment: This is the one that actually still works with Swift 4! Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I want to track the language chosen by the user in Settings app every time the user launches my app - that is not yet localized (my app is in English only). I adopted this logic:

1. create an *enum* to to make it easier to handle the languages in *array*

   ```
   enum Language: String {

   case none = ""
   case en = "English"
   case fr = "French"
   case it = "Italian"

   } // add as many languages you want
   ```
2. create a couple of *extension* to *Locale*

   ```
   extension Locale {

       static var enLocale: Locale {

           return Locale(identifier: "en-EN")
       } // to use in **currentLanguage** to get the localizedString in English

       static var currentLanguage: Language? {

           guard let code = preferredLanguages.first?.components(separatedBy: "-").last else {

               print("could not detect language code")

               return nil
           }

           guard let rawValue = enLocale.localizedString(forLanguageCode: code) else {

               print("could not localize language code")

               return nil
           }

           guard let language = Language(rawValue: rawValue) else {

               print("could not init language from raw value")

               return nil
           }
           print("language: \(code)-\(rawValue)")

           return language
       }
   }
   ```
3. When you need, you can simply use the extension

   ```
   if let currentLanguage = Locale.currentLanguage {
       print(currentLanguage.rawValue)
       // Your code here.
   }
   ```

Comment: Love the extension :). Wouldnt it makes more sense returning none if it's not able to read somehow. because that way that value can be used to make some value.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift, You can get the locale using.

```
let locale = Locale.current.identifier
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I use in Swift 5 Xcode 11:

Inside the class variables:

```
let languagePrefix = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first?.prefix(2)
```

This comes as a string. It returns 2 characters, i.e. "en", "es", "de"...

From this I can easily determine what language to display:

```
 if languagePrefix == "es" { self.flipCard.setTitle("última carta", for: .normal) }
 if languagePrefix == "en" { self.flipCard.setTitle("Last Card", for: .normal) }
```

If you want the full information of the language, then remove ?.prefex(2)

Answer (score 2):

in most cases you want to get the language code of the current app UI, to send over an API to get localized response

```
extension Bundle {
    
    var currentLocalizedUILanguageCode: String {
        guard let code = Bundle.main.preferredLocalizations.first?.components(separatedBy: "-").first else {
            return Locale.current.languageCode ?? "en"
        }
        return code
    }
    
}
```

use like

```
headers["X-Language"] = Bundle.main.currentLocalizedUILanguageCode
```

Answer (score 0):

Almost none of the answers are correct. This is a working Swift 5.7 solution. ""

```
extension Locale {
    // Gets the language of the device, had to remove the content of AppleLanguages since `preferredLanguages`
    // is combining the result from multiple APIs. AppleLanguage is then set to the old value
    static var preferredLanguageCode: String {
        let appleLanguages = UserDefaults.standard.stringArray(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")

        guard let preferredLanguage = preferredLanguages.first,
              let code = Locale(identifier: preferredLanguage).languageCode else {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(appleLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
            return "en"
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(appleLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        return code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var languageCode = ""
 if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
   if let language = NSLocale.current.language.languageCode {
     languageCode = language.identifier
   }
 } else {
   if let language = NSLocale.current.languageCode {
     languageCode = language
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

use this function for get your system's current language code from iOS devices

```
    func getSystemLanguageCode() -> String {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    let pref_Language = NSLocale.preferredLanguages[0] as String //"fr-IN"
    let language = pref_Language.components(separatedBy: "-") //["fr","IN"]
    let lang_Code = language.first?.lowercased() ?? "" //"fr"
    UserDefaults.standard.set([lang_Code], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    
    return lang_Code
}
```

Comment: This is not just getting, it is also setting. It is containing the correct answer but it is misleading.