# Detecting iphone language and change app lamguage

Tags: swift, xcode6

I want my app to detect iphone language automatically and changes my app language to the same.Can anybody help me with the code

Answer (score 1):

This provides what you want:

[How to get current language code with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)

It returns a language code, which can be used to determine the language.

Answer (score 0):

You need to internationalise your App, it's a very common thing to do. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014)