# getting current used language in the app

Tags: ios, swift, locale

I am trying to find out the `current used language` in my app as in this link:

[How to get current language code with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)

```
     let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

but it's keep crashing and got this error:

[image]

How to solve this and why am getting this error?

this only happens in classes like:

```
class ButtonText: UIButton {
    let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 35, bottom: 0, right: 0);
    let padding2 = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 35);
    let pre = Locale.preferredLanguages[0]

    override open func titleRect(forContentRect bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        //if pre != "ar"{
        if let code = Locale.current.languageCode , code != "ar" {
            return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding)
        }else {
            titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
            return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding2)
        }
        /* }else{
         titleLabel?.textAlignment = .left
         return UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(bounds, padding2)
         }*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Just share you Code not image

Answer (score 1):

Your code in image have no error we need previous code and how you use this button to know where is exception

Current languageCode with  this line is optional string

```
Locale.current.languageCode
```

but with this line is not optional

```
Locale.preferredLanguages[0]
```

So try this and tell me result

```
 override func titleRect(forContentRect contentRect: CGRect) -> CGRect {

    if let code = Locale.current.languageCode , code != "en" {

    } else{

    }
}
```

Comment: just added the code where i have the error ... tried yours and got same error

Comment: when used inside controllers works fine only in classes like the one i uploaded

Comment: So error not in languageCode it in Button creation , so update question with what you do on UIbutton

Comment: what do you mean by what do you do on UIbutton?

Comment: At Button creation class and how you use it , and when

Comment: in the mainstoryboard i assigned button to a custom class which is the above

Comment: Where is creation of UIbutton to test it in my end

Comment: the creation is from the main story board .. i didn't create it in code..

Comment: and you just override this titleRect