# Determine localized language of macOS device?

Tags: swift, macos, localization

I want to get the language of the device (macOS). All I found is a bunch of examples for the app itself or the prefered user setting, not the device itself:

`Locale.preferredLanguages`   => ["en", "de-DE"]  (I'm using english XCode, non localized app and german macOS)

I want to set the labels of the Finder as extended attributes the same language as the OS itself. For me it is "de", regardless of the localization of the app.

I also found some old tips (5 - 10 years old) which needed a lot of changes in code, but still don't work.
What's the correct function call to get the language used by the OS to set color names like "Rot" or "Red" later on? (e.g. "de" for my setup)

Comment: Duplicate of [How to get current language code with Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591167/how-to-get-current-language-code-with-swift)

Comment: No, as described it does NOT show OS setting.

Comment: What is the order of the languages in the system prefs?

Answer (score 0):

I found an solution:

((Locale.current as NSLocale).object(forKey: NSLocale.Key.languageCode)! as! String)

Comment: It returns the same as `NSLocale.current.languageCode`: the first preferred language that is supported by the app.

Comment: Great, that's better!